# Shape recognition, cropping and rotation

Tags: linux, images, image-editing

I have a book where each page is a photographed picture (double sided). The next step is to clean up the images. Issue number one is that on quite a few pages the page is rotated a little bit right or left.

Sample images to illustrate. (These are not the *real* pictures as they are not available right now.)

Before:

[image: skewed]

After:

[image: normalized]

Is there a way to  recognize shapes, such as a page, or edges, and use that to align the image so that it is not rotated (by a few degrees)?

The book is about 1900 pages, so I am looking for an automated way, as opposed to doing it manually in, for example, GIMP.

Comment: Are the images of book pages?  If so it will be tough to automate.  Unless you unbind the pages, it's difficult to eliminate edges that are at different angles.  There are tools that involve your adding a reference line to the image to identify the basis for rotation, but 1900 pages...

Comment: @fixer1234: Yes. As in sample images in post. About 950 pictures. If I could unbind the book I'd request a scan as opposed to photographs. The thought was that some utility could approximately identify the rectangle which is the book, crop and rotate it.

Comment: If you haven't already scanned, some scanning software has an automatic straightening/de-skewing option.  Results will be mixed if there are competing angles.  That's a problem with open books if the images aren't captured in a fixture the ensures everything is squared (book opening & camera).  So the feature exists, and you are likely to also find it in image manipulation software, maybe even more common in something like software intended to clean up cellphone snapshots.  Not all programs will feature batch processing, but ones with a CLI would at least allow you to write a script.

Comment: If the photos haven't been taken yet, the easiest solution is to do it right in the first place.  Use a fixture (it can match the background color), to position and align the book.  Archivists use something that has a top glass and often a vertical center bar to spread the pages squarely and flatten them.  Mount the camera in a fixture or tripod to ensure that it is centered and square in every plane.  Once it's set up, the camera can be zoomed to maximize use of the available pixels and eliminate the need for cropping.